# Rails console in development doesn't load the classes Rails 3.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, development-environment

The rails console comand  does not load the modification in the classes. I'm not using config.threadsafe!
config/environments/development.rb

```
config.cache_classes = false
```

Comment: Did you save changes in your class files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use "reload!" for changes in class when in Rails console.

```
config.cache_classes = false
```

means class files will be reload every **request**, not on Rails console.

Comment: Correct! Thank you very much!